# Better way to store references in a map

Tags: go, reference, anonymous-function

What would be a better way than this to store references to structs in a map? Right now I'm using an anonymous function so that all the map keys don't end up with the same reference. I'm sure there has to be a more elegant way to do it.

```
m := make(map[string]*Result)
for result := range results {
    func(r Result) {
        m[r.Key] = &r
    }(result)
}
```

**Update:** `results` is a channel of simple structs

Comment: What's the type of `results`?

Comment: It's a channel of a simple struct `Results`

Comment: BTW, if you haven't already, think about whether there is a reason to store `*Result` in the map, or just `Result`. Given that you already have to make a copy, you could make the map-entry the copy, if there's no strong reason not to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to store a pointer to a newly allocated value:

```
m := make(map[string]*Result)
for r := range results {
    r := r
    m[r.Key] := &r
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In what situation would I want to do the second? Doesn't it take away the advantages of storing references if I copy the value?

Comment: The code doesn't work for iterating channels:
`iteration over results (variable of type chan Result) permits only one iteration variable`

Comment: I see, but doesn't this solution make an extra copy of the value? In this case my code above would be more efficient, no? But perhaps I'm wrong about how Go handles it internally.

Comment: Your function closure makes a copy too - when passing by value - and also incurs a function stack call. Cerise's solution makes a copy with no function call.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to copy the result struct:

```
m := make(map[string]*Result)
for result := range results {
    result:=result
    m[result.Key] = &result
}
```